# Docker Registry incorrectly claims an expired CA cert

Tags: ssl, docker, docker-registry

I followed the Docker Registry installation docs precisely, and have a registry running on a remote Ubuntu VM. On that VM, the Docker container is running with the following command:

```
docker run -d -p 5000:5000 --restart=always --name registry \
    -v `pwd`/auth:/auth \
    -e "REGISTRY_AUTH_HTPASSWD_REALM=Registry Realm" \
    -e REGISTRY_AUTH_HTPASSWD_PATH=/auth/htpasswd \
    -v `pwd`/certs:/certs \
    -e REGISTRY_HTTP_TLS_CERTIFICATE=/certs/registry.crt \
    -e REGISTRY_HTTP_TLS_KEY=/certs/registry.key \
    registry:2
```

On the remote VM, I have the following directory structure:

```
/home/myuser/
    certs/
        registry.crt
        registry.key
/etc/docker/certs.d/myregistry.example.com:5000/
    ca.crt
    ca.key
```

The `ca.crt` is the same exact cert as `~/certs/registry.crt` (just renamed); same goes for `ca.key` and `registry.key` being the same/just renamed. I created the `ca*` files per a suggestion from the error output you'll see below.

I am *almost* 100% sure the CA cert is still valid, although any help ruling that out (e.g. how can I actually tell?) would be appreciated. When I start the container and look at the Docker logs, I don't see any errors.

I then attempt to login from my local laptop (Mac):

```
docker login myregistry.example.com:5000
```

It queries me for my username, password and *email* (although I don't recall ever specifying an email when setting up Basic Auth). After entering these *correctly* (I have checked and double checked...) I get the following error:

```
myuser@mymachine:~/tmp$docker login myregistry.example.com:5000
Username: my_ciuser
Password: 
Email: myuser@example.com
Error response from daemon: invalid registry endpoint https://myregistry.example.com:5000/v0/:
unable to ping registry endpoint https://myregistry.example.com:5000/v0/ v2 ping attempt failed with error:
Get https://myregistry.example.com:5000/v2/: x509: certificate has expired or is not yet valid
v1 ping attempt failed with error: Get https://myregistry.example.com:5000/v1/_ping: x509:
certificate has expired or is not yet valid. If this private registry supports only HTTP or
HTTPS with an unknown CA certificate, please add 
`--insecure-registry myregistry.example.com:5000` to the daemon's
arguments. In the case of HTTPS, if you have access to the registry's CA
certificate, no need for the flag; simply place the CA certificate
at /etc/docker/certs.d/myregistry.example.com:5000/ca.crt
```

So from my perspective, I guess the following are possible:

- The CA cert is invalid (*if so, why?!?*)
- The CA cert is an intermediary cert (*if so, how can I tell?*)
- The CA cert is expired (*if so, how do I tell?*)
- This is a bad error message, and some other facet of the registry is not configured properly (*if so, how do I troubleshoot further?*)
- Perhaps my cert is not located in the correct place on the server, or doesn't have the right permissions set (*if so, where does the cert need to be?*)
- Something else that I would never expect in a million years

Any ideas/thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

As said in the error message:

> ... In the case of HTTPS, if you have access to the registry's CA
>   certificate, no need for the flag; simply **place the CA certificate
>   at /etc/docker/certs.d/myregistry.example.com:5000/ca.crt**

where `myregistry.example.com:5000` - your CN with port.

You should copy your `ca.crt` into each Docker Daemon that will connect to your Docker Registry and put it in this folder: `/etc/docker/certs.d/myregistry.example.com:5000/ca.crt`

After this action you need to restart Docker daemon, for example, via  `sudo service docker stop && service docker start` on CentOS (or call similar procedure on your OS).

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar error:
Then I added my private registry to the insecureregistries list.
See below image for docker-desktop
[image]